# How to use StoryBoard quick build a collectionView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I build a `collectionView` inside a `tableView` cell,like below picture show:
[image]
then drag a `IBOutlet` in Custom `UITableViewCell` named ServicePromotionItemCell setting `UICollectionViewDataSource`.

main code:

```
#import "ServicePromotionCollectionView.h"
#import <HexColor.h>
@interface ServicePromotionItemCell ()<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ServicePromotionCollectionView *promotionCollectionView;
@end

@implementation ServicePromotionItemCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];

    _promotionCollectionView = [[ServicePromotionCollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    _promotionCollectionView.delegate = self;
    _promotionCollectionView.dataSource = self;
    [_promotionCollectionView registerClass:ServicePromotionCollectionViewCell.self forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ServicePromotionCollectionCell"];
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 3;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ServicePromotionCollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
}
```

But when I run app,It seem not init `UICollectionView`, does I miss something?
Please help me.Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: check collection view data source is imported or not,check your delegate is assigned to particular view controller,check the data is nill or it have some values which you want to display it.

Comment: everything you method is setting..

Comment: Can the answer be more specific. What was the exact reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check collection view data source is imported or not,check your delegate is assigned to particular view controller,check the data is nill or it have some values which you want to display it